# What is the advantage of direct memory access?

Tags: embedded, dma

If the CPU cannot access the bus during DMA transfers so must wait on the bus to be released, how does using DMA provide any performance advantage?

Comment: @SamuelLiew : Hardly "opinion based".  Are you sure you posess the expertise to make that decision?  The OP is under the misapprehension that because there is bus contention DMA can have no advantage.  The fact that that is not the case is not a matter of opinion.  The question is of particular interest to embedded systems developers, but I suspect that is not your domain of expertise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be bus contention, but it is still likely to be faster than the alternative which is typically interrupt driven I/O which has a huge software overhead.  Typically the DMA transfer will not use the maximum memory bandwidth (except for memory-to-memory transfers perhaps) because peripheral devices tend to be far slower than the memory.  The DMA controller will *interleave* CPU access.

Moreover bus contention is not a given, many microcontrollers segment their memory on separate buses so access by the CPU to memory on one bus can occur concurrently with DMA operations in memory on another.  For example Harvard architecture devices have independent buses for code and data memory, so can fetch op-codes and data simultaneously, but the reduced access load on the data memory (because not all instructions require memory operands to be fetched) advantages DMA.

Further, some microcontrollers such as many in the STM32 series (Cortex-M so also Harvard architecture) segment their on-chip SRAM on separate buses (as well as an external memory interface on a separate bus).  Typically there will be some segment of SRAM smaller than the other segments - 4K or 16K perhaps - that is ideal for exclusive use for DMA buffering.  Using the memory in this way can have a significant impact on performance by avoiding bus contention.

Another feature of some STM32 parts is *core coupled memory* (CCM) which is not available for DMA or bit-banding, but if used for most CPU data processing, leaves other on-chip SRAM available for DMA further reducing bus contention.

Other microprocessors may have similar memory segmentation.  To take advantage of such memory architecture you typically require a custom linker script and possibly linker directives in the code, to allow segments to be identified and objects to be explicitly assigned to them. This will be toolchain specific.

Comment: *"the alternative which is typically interrupt driven I/O"* -- Actually that would be programmed I/O.  See [dma vs interrupt-driven i/o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318145/dma-vs-interrupt-driven-i-o/38165400#38165400).

Comment: @sawdust I see your point, but that is more general. I included the caveat _"typically"_ for a reason; I am not suggesting that it is the opposite of DMA, merely an alternative.  It is "typical" because polled I/O does not allow the same background/foreground processing, so is the less comparable alternative.