# HAL Libraries: What is the difference between DMA implementation in hal_dma.h and hal_uart.h libraires?

Tags: uart, dma

I am trying to connect STM32G070 microcontroller with Quectel BC660K-GL via UART in DMA mode, using HAL libraries. There are two libraries both defining DMA communication functions (`stm32g0xx_hal_uart.h` and `stm32g0xx_hal_dma.h`). I am using *[Description of STM32G0 HAL and low-layer drivers](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2319-description-of-stm32g0-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)* manual. According to the manual `_hal_dma.h` defines *Interrupt mode IO operation* [(page 215.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coa90.png), while `_hal_uart.h` provides, according to the description given in the library, *Non-Blocking mode API's with DMA* [(lines 1054-1059)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyG03.png). Hence I'm using DMA in order to offload CPU, which library would be preferred?

Comment: "*According to the manual _hal_dma.h defines Polling IO operation*" -- No, you are misunderstanding the manual.  Apparently you are incorrectly conflating "interrupt mode" and "*Polling IO*".  (Study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318145/dma-vs-interrupt-driven-i-o/38165400#38165400)  That manual excerpt describes using DMA transfers with DMA interrupts, and no "*polling*" is involved.  "*Hence I'm using DMA in order to offload CPU...*" -- In order to "*use DMA*", you need a DMA controller (aka DMAC), which has to be programmed (with source, destination, count) for each DMA transfer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, *Interrupt mode IO operation* is correctly. My main confusion comes from similarity between the functions defined in these libraries, therefore, I will try to summarize. According to manual, when *HAL_DMA_Start_IT()* (`from _hal_dma.h`)  is done, **XferCpltCallback()** function will be called (part of the *__DMA_HandleTypeDef* structure), and *HAL_UART_Tx(RX)HalfCpltCallback* **will or will not be** called depending of is it USART1 global interrupt enabled or disabled.

Comment: On the other hand, after *HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA()* is done, function *HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback()* is called also depending of is it USART1 global interrupt enabled or disabled ( I am using STM32CubeMX, and USART1 interrupt can be enabled under *NVIC Settings* tab).